# build by tfs2013 for tfs2012 collections over internet network

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2012, tfs-2013

I have 2 tfs servers: tfs2012 and tfs2013
They are in the internet and have dns names.
There is no AD domains on it.

I have some projects and collections on tfs2012.

Now I want that tfs2013 will do build for projects, that are on tfs2012.

How can I do that?

When on tfs2013 I click "build service properties" and name of tfs2012 server I can see collections that are hosted on it.
When I click on collection then OK I have message:

> the register command is not supported for Team foundation Server [name] because the server is not compatible

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, TSF 2013 can use (communicate with) 2012 Build Controllers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181712.aspx), but not the other way around.